# Multiple requests at the same time bypasses checks

Tags: php, laravel

Basically I have an online game built with PHP (Laravel). It's functionality is quite simple. When the player equips an item, it checks to see if an item of the same type is already equipped. If there is no item of the same type equipped, it will then go ahead and equip the item.

This is done by simply setting the changing the equipped flag on the Inventory model to 1. Something like this

```
        if($alreadyequippeditem == false){
        //equip current item
        $inventory = \App\Inventory::find($item->pivot->id);
        $inventory->equipped = 1;
        $inventory->save();
        }
```

However, if one does it fast enough, a person can equip two (or even more) items of the same time at the same time. Essentially bypassing the check.

It seems to me that the two requests are being handled by the server at the exact same time, and they equip the items at the exact same time and it essentially bypasses the checks. This may explain why two items can be equipped, because at the time the requests are ran, they don't recognise each other. I may be wrong, but it's the only explanation I can think of.

How can I get around this? Is there a way of limiting it so only 1 request is sent at the same time? I can't recall ever encountering this problem when I've built systems with core PHP and no framework so I have no idea if its something caused by a laravel configuration. I understand I may be able to get around it using queues (although I haven't looked into it much), but I would much rather find a solution that works site-wide as this specific problem affects many areas of the system.

Comment: Seems like an SQL race condition with checking and updating. You probably want to wrap the checking/equipping process in a transaction and lock the row.

Comment: Yeah it's a race condition. You need to implement the built in locking with transactions.

Comment: If you can wait like 10 minutes I'll put up an answer with documentation links and example. I'm almost to a computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Issue (race condition)

What you're experience is a classic textbook example of a [race condition](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/race-condition):

> A race condition is an undesirable situation that occurs when a device
>   or system attempts to perform two or more operations at the same time,
>   but because of the nature of the device or system, the operations must
>   be done in the proper sequence to be done correctly.

## Example fix with all the essentials

Luckily for us, this is not a new problem, nor is it a very hard one to fix. Especially when using Laravel:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Inventory;
use App\Player;
use Request;


class BustRaceConditionsController extends Controller
{
    public function EquipItem(Request $request)
    {
        \DB::beginTransaction();

        $player = $player->where("id", $request->user()->player_id)->lockForUpdate()->first();

        $success = true;

        try {

            /* some logic here to check if item is equiped or not */

            if (itemIsEquiped()) {

                $success = false;

            } else {

                /* lets equip the item, then save it, and then we need to commit it to the DB */

                $player->itemEquip = $item;
                $player->save();

                \DB::commit();

            }


        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            $success = false;
            \DB::rollback();

        }
        return ['success' => $success];
    }
}
```

1. This is a very crude example on how this is done in Laravel, but essentially whats happening here is that we start a [DB transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#database-transactions) which allows us to essentially make sure everything works, or nothing does. This is especially useful in this situation.
2. Next, we grab all the data we want from the model, but notice here that I am using [`lockForUpdate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#pessimistic-locking) in the method chain. This is to ensure that nothing else can read or write until my changes are either committed or fail, thus releasing the lock.
3. Finally, we need to either commit the change to the DB, or ultimately fail the change and roll everything back.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect! I was pulling my hair out wondering why it was not working, then I found out online that the engine needs to be InnoDB and not MyISAM. Now everything is working perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: As Derek is too humble to say it, but provided a quality answer @slothinspace mark the answer as correct